# Finding WebLogic server process on my database and its current state

Tags: oracle, weblogic, weblogic11g

We're using `WebLogic 11g` with `Oracle DB 11g`.

Perhaps there is no way to do it just using database queries since the deployment name of any application is stored on WL server.

The query below shows some useful info but I'm not able to see the deployed application name.

```
SELECT distinct a.program,
a.last_call_et,
a.osuser,
a.process,
a.machine,
a.port,
a.terminal,
a.sid,
a.module,
b.sql_text 
FROM v$session a, v$sql b, v$process c
WHERE machine in ('wlservername') AND a.status = 'ACTIVE' AND a.sql_id = b.sql_id
and a.paddr=c.addr;
```

Comment: Oracle DB and WebLogic Server are 2 different products. They are "linked" via SQL connections initiated by WebLogic. The database is not "aware" of applications deployed in WebLogic. What you can do is setting properties on sql connections to set  information on db sessions.

Answer (score 0):

As you guessed the informations about `WebLogic` deployments is managed only on his side. If you want to check deployment state, version or any other data, simply modify your application to store this information on a Oracle DB table.

Ex. On application context creation you can set a deployed flag on a table and then uncheck it when the context is destroyed.